# Fail to use Maven to build Paho project on Win7

Tags: android, maven, mqtt, paho

I've tried to create an MQTT project on Android by using [PAHO](http://www.eclipse.org/paho/clients/android/sample/).

According to the description, I clone the source code to my computer, and using

> mvn clean install

to build the project.

I download org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0, and expecting to get:

1. org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.0.jar and
2. org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.0.jar

but after running mvn clean install, I just can get org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.0.jar, so I can't build the project.

and here is the message output:

```
C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.and roid.service>mvn install -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model fororg.eclipse.paho:android-service:jar:0.1
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ org.eclipse.paho:java-parent:${paho.version}, C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\pom.xml, line 7, column 11
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 95, column 21
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building android-service 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- templating-maven-plugin:1.0-alpha-3:filter-sources (filter-src) @ android-service ---
[INFO] Request to add 'C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\src\main\java-templates' folder. Not added since it does not exist.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ android-service ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) @ android-service ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (generate-manifest) @ android-service ---
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.910 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-01-15T13:16:59+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/153M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (generate-manifest) on project android-service: Cannot find C:\Users\Janniin\
Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target\classes (manifest goal must be run after compile phase) -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.felix:maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (generate-manifest) on projec
t android-service: Cannot find C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target\classes (manifest goal must b
e run after compile phase)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot find C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target\classes (manifest goal must be run after compile phase)
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute(ManifestPlugin.java:73)
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:264)
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.BundlePlugin.execute(BundlePlugin.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Janniin\Downloads\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target\classes
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.getAnalyzer(ManifestPlugin.java:175)
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.getManifest(ManifestPlugin.java:114)
        at org.apache.felix.bundleplugin.ManifestPlugin.execute(ManifestPlugin.java:69)
        ... 23 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Could anyone give me some suggest to solve this problem??

Thx a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following the information described here https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/java/ in order to `build from source`.

After running `mvn package -DskipTests` (it took some time) I got:

- **org.eclipse.paho.android.service-1.0.1.jar** which is located under *`..\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target`*
- **org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3-1.0.1.jar** which is located under *`..\org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java\org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3\target`*

Comment: Thank you so much!! It really works!!

Since I'm not really familar with Git, I didn't use Git to clone the project,  instead I download the project from the web.

Thanks to @zlinks' advice, I try it by using SourceTree's terminal. And It really works!!

Comment: I am facing the same problem but this not solve mine :S am I missing something ?! (ps also manually download org.eclipse.paho.mqtt.java-1.0.0 )

Comment: Finally I got it work following these steps after I download org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3 using git (It seems different from the manually version where I got BUILD FAILURE "Cannot find C:\Users\..\org.eclipse.paho.android.service\target\classes"  - Network proxy can be the reason